# Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: hibernate-validator, quarkus

Quarkus application (0.19.1), created from QuarkEE artifact fails to start with:

```
[io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError ..
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.HibernateValidatorRecorder
```

**EDIT**
I've opened a ticket for it:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause** was a bean validation constraint `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` on the static factory method of the enum class. Simplified example:

```java
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE;

    public static Gender fromCode(@NotNull String code) {
        return Gender.valueOf(code);
    }
}
```

and having this dependency in your pom:

```xml
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
       <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Confusing thing is that static factory methods on simple POJO class works.

**Note**
I'm aware that validation of static methods is not supported by the Bean Validation specification. It is just a hint for IDE.

> **Java EE 8 Validating Constructors and Methods:** Bean Validation constraints may be placed on the parameters of nonstatic methods and constructors and on the return values of nonstatic methods. Static methods and constructors will not be validated.

Comment: Could you open a Quarkus issue on GitHub with a reproducer? Thanks!